Establish TCP connection between 2 computers on public network
I am using sockets for a project at work.
I created 2 simple scripts just to test that it would function, and the client always times out and won't connect to the server.
I have gone through a lot of the obvious fixes. Python is allowed through the defender firewall (both in and outgoing) on both machines.
The server code is as follows:
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 2727))
s.listen(5)

print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))

while True:
    clientsock, address = s.accept()
    print("connection from {0} established".format(address))
    clientsock.send(bytes("test", "utf-8"))

The client code is as follows:
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ip = input()

s.connect((ip, 2727))

msg = s.recv(1024)

print(msg.decode("utf-8"))

I run both scripts, input the IP of the server into the client, nothing happens for a solid while and then I am presented with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\~~\Downloads\OJEsock.py", line 7, in <module>
    s.connect((ip, 2727))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I checked and the server is listening properly. The wifi at work is a public network, and it was my concern that perhaps (because of however the open wifi functions) the machines arent seen as on the same local network, but arp -a shows that they are, and they both have the same default gateway listed under ipconfig (if that means anything).
What am I missing? How can I make this work?

What IP(s) are actually assigned to the server machine? Your server should print out all of them, not just the single one from gethostbyname(). What IP are you trying to connect your client socket to? Did you try connecting to the server's host name instead of its IP? Is the client machine able to ping the server machine? Try using gethostbyname_ex() or getaddrinfo() or getifaddrs() or other related API to get all of the IPs assigned to the server. Maybe the IP you are connecting to is not reachable from the client.

The local IP of the server is 10.129.33.210. I had been attempting to connect to the IP read out by the server program. I did just try connecting to the host name instead of ip, it produced a new error: getaddrinfo failed.

gethostbyname_ex() returns no alternative IPs or aliases

Is there reason why you put "0.0.0.0" in server? Did you actually put 0.0.0.0 or is it redacted IP?

@jupiterbjy 0.0.0.0 is INADDR_ANY, it will bind the socket to all local IPv4 adapters on the server. A client can then connect to any IP that is assigned to the server. s.bind(('', 2727)) accomplishes the same thing

@Matt are you sure the client and server are actually on the same LAN? Did you try pinging the server from the client, like I suggested? Is the server behind a firewall/router that the client has to pass through to reach the server?

@RemyLebeau thought it was weird as document says use '' to represent INADDR_ANY and not the other way around, good to know

"Establish TCP connection between 2 computers on public network" 10.129.33.210 is not on the public Internet.

@RonMaupin "The wifi at work is a public network". If both client and server are connected to the same WiFi, they should be on the same network and be able to see each other.

@Matt this seems less about a coding issue and more about a networking issue, so you might have better luck asking on [sf] instead.

@RemyLebeau, my point is that he is saying that address is a public address, but it is clearly not.

@RonMaupin nowhere in the OP's question or comments does it say that IP is a public Internet IP. Only that the IP is the server's local network IP, and that the network is public Wifi network, not a public Internet network.

@RemyLebeau, two computer on a public network is in the title of the question. To me that means there are two computers on a public network. "The wifi at work is a public network" would mean it uses public addressing and is accessible from the public Internet, else it would say that it is a private network. If the OP means something else, the question should say that instead of claiming a public network.

@RemyLebeau apologies for the delay in response. I am inclined to agree about it being a networking issue as I have successfully run similar code on home internet before. I am going to look into alternate methods for this project because tracking down enough superiors to figure out whats really going on behind the scenes just isnt worth it.

@RonMaupin Touch grass? Mr. Lebeau is correct in his interpretation of the question. I meant public network in a colloquial sense that the wifi is intended for public use. I did not intend to imply anything about connections via external or "public" IPs. I thought that would have been pretty obvious given that the question states both computers are connected to the same network and the IPs are local IPs.

You must mean a guest network. It is still a private network, even if anyone is allowed to use it. As a network engineer, I get asked to perform or provide various things, and misuse of terminology causes many problems. Programmers need to be pedantic, else they get syntax errors or introduce bugs.

It's possible to set up a public wifi network where different computers are blocked from communicating with each other - only the internet is allowed. Maybe ask the network admin if it's set up that way.
